# C#: using OR (short circuited version) for assignment

Tags: c#, lua

In **Lua** there is a nice feature for quickly checking if the result of a statement is `nil` or not and using short circuited version of **or** to react to the situation; something such as:

```
text = GetTextFromUser() or "default text"
```

which translates as assign the return value of `GetTextFromUser()` to `text` and if `GetTextFromUser()` returned `nil`, then assign `"default text"` to `text`

which basically is nice trick to use short circuit evaluation of `or` operator for assignment.

I'm wondering if c# `||` operators also has such capabilities or not. If no, what is the shortest way to achieve the same behavior? ternary operator? if statement?

Comment: [TernaryOperator]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ty67wk28.aspx

Comment: text = GetTextFromUser() ?? "default text"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe the null-coalescing operator? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ie/library/ms173224.aspx

```
string a;
string b = a ?? "default value";
```

So your example would become:

```
string text = GetTextFromUser() ?? "default text"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple method to return default value if condition fails

```
string GetValueOrDefault(string value, Func<bool, string> condition,
    string defaultValue = "") => condition(value) ? value: defaultValue;
```

Usage

```
var text = GetValueOrDefault(GetTextFromUser(), o => o != nil, "default text");
```

P.S.: TODO generic version.